# CheckBox and timedialog

Tags: android

The 5th param of Method TimePickerDialog() is false all the time, the boolean value check is not being passed to dialog's onCreate except for the first time.

Here is my code:

```
checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
            check = true;
            checkBox.setText("24 Format is set");
        } else {
            check = false;
            checkBox.setText("AM/PM Format is set");
        }
    }
});

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case IDD_DLG:
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            mMimute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            return new TimePickerDialog(this, mlistener, mHour, mMimute, check);

        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

I used status method to set the 5th param. But the problem still persists:

```
private Boolean status() {
    if (checkBox.isChecked())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the time picker dialog using another method than a depriciated one. Replace your button setOnClickListener() with this.

```
 but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("checcccked", check + "2");

            TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(Activity_activity.this,
                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                              int minute) {
                            mHour = hourOfDay;
                            mMimute = minute;
                            update();
                        }
                    }, mHour, mMimute, check);
            timePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but the code not works correctlu again. I try 2 path  which offered  Akash Patel and  Karun Shrestha.

Comment: Can you send me the project at kars.kit35@gmail.com?